# Submachine state in enterprise architect

Tags: enterprise-architect, state-diagram

How to create a submachine state in enterprise architect 13, where the state represents a state machine and links you to it? If exported to XMI, the state should have an ID tag that points you to the state machine.

Comment: _links you to it_ what is _it_??

Comment: "it" is the state machine, the submachine state created can link u to the respective state machine that it represents